# "Provider Load Failure" when running ANY cmdlet in Powershell v2.0

Tags: powershell

I have a couple workstations that apparently has a GPO applied to them that implements some security measures.  Unfortunately, it also appears that something has broke Powershell on them.

Whenever I attempt ANY cmdlet at all it hangs for a few minutes and finally gives a message "Provider Load Failure".

Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an organizational unit (OU) that doesn't have any GPOs applying to it. Move the computer into that OU, refresh Group Policy, reboot the computer, and see if it resolves. Assuming it does resolve the issue, slowly link the GPOs to the new OU, one by one, and see what breaks it.

Comment: These GPOs have hundreds of settings in them.  Even if I could narrow it down to one, it'd still take me hours to narrow it down that way.  What does Powershell do in the background when it attempts to load a provider?  If I could at least at a clue it'd help out considerably.

Comment: That's really under-the-hood stuff you're talking about. Assuming the message is even talking about `PSProviders` (eg. Registry, Filesystem, Certificate, WS-Man, etc.), it doesn't explain why any cmdlet would fail. The right course of action in a scenario like this is to start undoing whatever broke it, and re-introduce the custom configuration settings as appropriate.